# Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException:

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, mapping

Hi i am trying simple hibernate program but not able to fix this issue can anyone help

UserDetails.class

```
package org.pavan.dto;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class UserDetails {
@Id
private int userId;
private String userName;
public int getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(int userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
```

}

HibernateTest.java

package org.pavan.hibernate;

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.pavan.dto.UserDetails;

public class HibernateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    UserDetails user =new UserDetails();
    user.setUserId(1);
    user.setUserName("First User");
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("C:\\Users\\pavan\\workspace\\FirstHibernateProject\\src\\hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
```

~ Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java
  ~
  ~ License: GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL), version 2.1 or later.
  ~ See the lgpl.txt file in the root directory or http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.html.
  -->

```
<session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernatedb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">admin</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="org.pavan.dto.UserDetails"/>

</session-factory>
```

Error:

INFO: Configuration resource: C:\Users\pavan\workspace\FirstHibernateProject\src\hibernate.cfg.xml
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: C:\Users\pavan\workspace\FirstHibernateProject\src\hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
    at org.pavan.hibernate.HibernateTest.main(HibernateTest.java:14)

Can anyone help please

thanks in advance

Comment: `C:\Users\pavan\workspace\FirstHibernateProject\src\hibernate.cfg.xml` Does this file exist? The error says this file is not found. Where is your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file located?

Comment: i have saved it in Src folder outside all package,inside src

Comment: So you are saying you are able to find hibernate.cfg.xml in this path `C:\Users\pavan\workspace\FirstHibernateProject\src` ? Really weird that it is not able to find it. Just make sure there are no typos in the filename.

Comment: yes its present in the same folder. i dont why i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Some how it's not getting the hibernate‌​.cfg.xml in your path,

```
String path = String.format("%s/%s",System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src/hibernate.cfg.xml");

SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(path).buildSessionFactory();
```

---

or you can try it -> add a `resources` folder inside src and

> marked as resources directory

add move your hibernate.cfg.xml inside it,

```
 SessionFactory sessionFactory =   return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```